# Assigning value at same position in an array

Tags: c++

I have code:

```
T x,y;
T* t = new T[10];
t[0] = x;
t[0] = y;
```

What happens:
`new T[10]` makes array invoking default constructor.

`t[0]` is dereferenced pointer? 
So if I assign value `x`, `x` is copied (`T` copy constructor is invoked);

next if i assign `y` value to same position next copy constructor is invoked or assignment operator? Is old value properly destroyed?

Answer (score 7):

In your example:

```
T* t = new T[10];
```

invokes the default constructor of T (10 times).  Then

```
t[0] = x;
```

invokes the assignment operator.  This statement invokes no constructor.

Answer (score 2):

```
T* t = new T[10];
```

Creates `10` objects of the type `T` on the freestore(Heap) by calling default constructor of `T`.
Note that when you use `new` objects are always created on Freestore.

When you assign,

```
t[0] = x;
```

The copy assignment operator(`=`) a.k.a assignment is invoked.Neither the constructor nor the copy constructor is invoked here.

For simplicity remember the following rules:

- When a object is being created and assigned to in same statement, then copy constructor will be used. This is known as Copy Initialization.

**Example:**

```
   Myclass obj1;
   Myclass obj2 = obj1;  //obj2 is Created & Initialized in same statement
```

- When a object is already created in a previous statement and being assigned(`=`) to in another statement then the assignment operator will be called.

**Example:**

```
   Myclass obj1;      //obj1 is created
   Myclass obj2;      //obj2 is created
   obj2 = obj1;       //Already created object obj2 is assigned with obj1
```

Your examples fall in the second scenario.

Comment: so when I second time call t[0]=x; What happen with previous object that is on freestore?

Comment: @userbb: The contents of `x` will be simply copied in to the memory occupied by `t[0]`.Compiler generates an implicit `=` for every class which does this [shallow copying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy).